# Have problem to run Python command installed by pip in macOS Terminal

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm not a Python user, so know little about Python. But I have to install `stcgal` using pip3 following its [official guide](https://github.com/grigorig/stcgal).

```
pip3 install stcgal
```

However, if I run the installed command in terminal, it says `zsh: command not found`.

After a long searching, I find it was installed at `/Users/myUserName/Library/Python/3.8/bin/`. Though I can run the command with that path, it's very inconvenient. I wonder is there any way to run the code in any directory instead having to locate it explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create or edit your `/Users/yimingliu/.zshrc` file (if your macOS is older than macOS Catalina 10.15, then the file is `/Users/yimingliu/.bash_profile`), and add a line to add the python bin folder to your path:

```bash
export PATH=/Users/yimingliu/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
python -m stcgal -h
```